# Is Web Service in ASP.NET obsolete? What to use with ASP.NET 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-4.0

I have to write a simple Web Service application in ASP.NET. I read somewhere that Web Services is now obsolete and some new technologies like WCF is there.

But as the name suggests, Windows Communication Foundation, might me restricted to WinForms applications only and not for ASP.NET. What shall I use with Visual Studio 2010?

I want to build a simple Web Forms application and not MVC.

Comment: You can use WCF with WinForms, WPF, MVC and ASP.NET. Yes web services is old and dead and most will suggest you use WCF instead, but we still use web services (sadly) and still write them and they work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What shall I use with Visual Studio 2010?

You have many choices other than ASP.NET Web Services which are completely obsolete now. So if you are starting a new project and need to develop a web service you might consider:

- WCF
- ASP.NET Web API
- ServcieStack
- ASP.NET MVC

> But as the name suggests, Windows Communication Foundation, might me
>   restricted to WinForms applications only

The name is misleading. WCF has strictly nothing to do with Windows Forms only. You could host a WCF service in an ASP.NET application or self-host it if you want.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple Web Service** application in ASP.NET (webForm OR mvc) ?

My firt choice : **ASP.NET WebApi**

- Easy to unit test
- Easy to secure
- Restful

Still, **WCF** is pretty cool too because it is very well integrated with VS, and easy to configure through web.config

Both WebApi and WCF make it possible to **version** your web services.